# Create log messages in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

I want my WPF app to log unexpected errors to a text file that we can look at.

Is there any way to do this on our own?

an is there any opensource or third party tolls to use? if yes please

let me know.

Comment: take a look at NLog. Does it fit your needs?

Comment: There are plenty around, googling for "error logging c#" will probably show you a lot of them. Read [ask], your question is unsuitable for SO

Comment: Yes - numerous logging frameworks exists. Your problem is not "if they exist" but "which logging framework should I use?". An example is log4net.

Comment: Yes Dietz, let me check your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

http://nlog-project.org/

https://github.com/NLog/NLog

I hope this is helpful, open source project

Comment: Also log4net, available at https://logging.apache.org/log4net/ and also via NuGet.

Comment: Let me try NLog, i will comeback if i need any help. Thank you all for help.